# Recompute values in Postgres generated column after underlying function changed

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-function, generated-columns

Image a table with a generated column like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION extract_first_name(p_name text) RETURNS text
LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE
AS $$
    SELECT split_part(p_name, ' ', 1);
$$;

CREATE TABLE customers (
    id serial,
    name text,
    first_name text GENERATED ALWAYS AS (extract_first_name(name)) STORED
);
```

Later someone finds that the `extract_first_name` function is too simplistic and needs to be changed. It's then updated, but the values in the `first_name` column stays the same. How do we in the simplest and most efficient way recompute all the values in the `first_name` column to use the latest version of the function w/o locking the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A generated column is 'computed' on 2 events. When the row is Inserted and when the underlying column is Updated. Thus you need to Update every row with [something like](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=50101256762cfcd6707ba82aba5d51aa)

```
Update customers 
   set name = name;
```

This will, as needed, update every row in the table. But as Postgres uses a [MVCC](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/mvcc-intro.html) model this will not block others from selecting during the operation.

> The main advantage of using the MVCC model of concurrency control
> rather than locking is that in MVCC locks acquired for querying
> (reading) data do not conflict with locks acquired for writing data,
> and so reading never blocks writing and writing never blocks reading.
> PostgreSQL maintains this guarantee even when providing the strictest
> level of transaction isolation through the use of an innovative
> Serializable Snapshot Isolation (SSI) level.

However, you will need to lookout for deadlocks if you continue to allow updates during this process.

Comment: It's also computed when you add the generated column.